# Django table of 250k records - filter by datetime takes over a minute

Tags: django, datetime, filter, django-queryset

I have a Django model with 4 indexes, all set and installed correctly. One of the indexes is a DateTimeField. DB is Mysql.

Table/model has about 250k records. Fetching information from it is generally quick, usually I fetch information from it based on an indexed DateTimeField regarding past few hours ago data.

Problem is fetching info from it based on the DateTimeField regarding past data, say 7 days or 30 days ago. It usually takes about a minute to get the info.

Is there anything I can do to speed the access time?

One thing I consider doing is archiving the table and just keeping Summery information which is grouped and can squeeze the data to 1/100 of its current record count.

Comment: Can you show an example of the slow query?

Comment: Here is a slow query:

When from_time and to_time are say up to 24 hrs ago query info is fetched within maximum 1 second. When from_time and to_time is 7 days in the past it can take up to 50 seconds.

btcval_rs = CurrencyReadingData.objects.filter(base_currency=self.base_currency, quote_currency=self.quote_currency, exchange=self.exchange).filter(datetime__range=(from_time, to_time))

Comment: Are you using any software that optimizes things like searching massive DBs? Perhaps "caching software" might be relevant here. Correct me if I'm wrong.